# Validar CPF com data de nascimento

Tags: javascript, ajax

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No site R7 na parte de cadastro de e-mail uma validação é feita no número do CPF que esta relacionada com a data de nascimento como fazer algo parecido no meu formulário?
 dei uma olhada no código mas ta um pouco bagunçado
https://cadastro.r7.com/static/r7-cadastro/js/newUser-register.js
eu preciso apenas da parte que valida os 2 campos cpf + data_nasc validação de cpf com javascript não tem segredo a questão é como unir com a data de nasc.

Comment: Na verdade o CPF não possui associação direta com a data de nascimento. O que existe para validar o CPF é o algoritmo Módulo 11: http://www.goulart.pro.br/cbasico/Calculo_dv.htm

Comment: Veja a id desse inputs de data nascimento e cpf e faz uma busca no js e veja o procedimento

Comment: Então eu também achava que não existia; mas depois de tentar fazer um cadastro sem querer coloque a data de nascimento errada e não consegui continuar só foi possível criar a conta quando coloquei a data correta do aniversario. No site da receita só consegui consultar a situação do cpf com a data de nascimento mas lá ja existe a data no banco de dados e no r7 não.

Comment: O R7 provavelmente valida com os dados da receita para ver se as informações são condizentes

Comment: Seja lá como for; interessante como é feito essa parte, da mais segurança na hora de obter os dados diminuindo cadastros com erros.

Comment: Eu não usaria. O CPF já tem um mecanismo de validação que impede erros. Se você quiser validar a DATA em função da busca na receita para ver se bate, seria uma validação da DATA. Mesmo essa, eu não usaria - a não ser que fosse uma exigência que a data siga o que está registrado na receita. Neste caso a API a usar deveria ser fornecida.

Comment: Outro comentário, a não ser que seja como o Jeferson Assis falou, talvez o site use uma lógica que associa o número do CPF com uma faixa de ano de nascimento. Talvez exista isso, como poderia ser para placa de carros. Eu teria ressalvas quando a eficácia.

Comment: Pesquisei na internet não achei nada sobre isso :-/

Answer (score 7):

Rose, se você abrir a barra de ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador, ir para a aba network e fizer uns testes na página, verá que a URL que está sendo chamada e os parâmetros. Extraí um trecho para simulação, conforme abaixo:

```
$.post('https://cadastro.r7.com/ajax/validate/cpf'
    , { 'user.documentNumber':'111.111.111-11', 'user.birthDate':'01/01/1900' }
    , function (data) { 
        if (data == '') {
            alert('Válido');
        } else { 
            // Este trecho converte códigos de acentos
            // (ex.: &aacute; &ccedil;) nos seus respectivos caracteres.
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = data.message;
            alert(div.innerText);
        }
    }
);
```

Esse trecho só vai funcionar no próprio site do R7 (aba console das ferramentas de desenvolvedor) pois, por segurança, o navegador bloqueia requisições "cross-domain". Existem bibliotecas para burlar tais restrições, mas sempre existe a desvantagem de que, como o portal R7 não disponibilizou esse recurso com o intuito de compartilhá-lo com terceiros, um dia pare de funcionar sua validação e você tenha que estudar o código novamente e fazer as alterações necessárias. Não sei se vale a pena correr o risco.

É possível você criar uma página no seu servidor para enviar os dados para a Receita, incluindo o captcha, e recuperar o retorno mas cai na mesma desvantagem de ficar vulnerável às alterações da Receita. Um exemplo em C#, mas para CNPJ (vale para entender como a missão é complexa): http://fabianonalin.net.br/Fontes/consultar-cnpj

Talvez existam serviços de terceiros (pagos) que forneçam um WebService para realizar tais consultas, mas não sei até onde vale a pena fazer essa validação. Você pode dificultar ao máximo o usuário de preencher dados incorretos, executando a mesma validação no servidor, mas se ele estiver disposto a burlar, corre-se o risco do usuário utilizar dados de terceiros.

Ao decidir por qual caminho seguir, atualize a questão para que sirva de referência para outros programadores que encontrem esta página.

Comment: Pensando por esse lado tem razão; não vale apena, já que levaria muito tempo para implantar isso e sem garantia que vai funcionar permanente. Vou usar validação apenas no CPF e acrescentar o campo data de nascimento e qualquer coisa depois com esses dados posso fazer manualmente a consulta no site da receita para verificar; mais pra frente posso implantar a validação de usuário por SMS conferindo o numero de celular do mesmo; já uso em outro site um script que envia a senha de cadastro para o celular. obrigado a todos que tentou ajudar.